# Cannot assign function in EventTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

As you can see at the attached image, The OnDrag function is not appearing in the event trigger. It was assign before but when i re-open the project, it prompt as missing. It is still working though even with the missing prompt but my problem is when I change or transfer the script  to other gameobject. I cannot re assign it again.

```
public void OnDrag(BaseEventData eventData)
{
    RegisterPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

public void Test()
{
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which Unity Version is this?

There was [a BUG](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type?_ga=2.42604581.127594340.1571029466-241225422.1516255303) making the  **dynamic** parameter methods disappear and only display the static ones

Since they are very limited in which parameter can be passed static (`BaseEventData` not being one of them) it is now not longer listed.

Did you change the Unity version shortly? If so you should use one of the versions this bug was fixed for

`2018.4`, `2019.2` or `2020.1`

At least for `2019.2` I know it wasn't fixed before `2019.2.5` but maybe they also patched them back downwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to stick to official recomendations: use only the methods with no parameters or with simple type parameters with Event Triger component - int, string, float etc. Your method OnDrag looks like implemented interface method so it should be called if cursor drag over it will be detected and the object either a child of a Canvas or has an active collider attached, so you actually don't need additional event trigger here.